# Image effect on hover, filing place of image

Tags: image, hover, effect

I found one effect in this demo site (http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/51283.html in MENU subsite on hower on image) and I want to use something like that on my webpage, but I don't know how to do this "magic". Maybe somebody know is that can be writen only in css or i have to use JS/jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.itemsContainer {
    background:red; 
    float:left;
    position:relative
}
.itemsContainer:hover .play{display:block}
.play{
  position : absolute;
    display:none;
    top:20%; 
    width:40px;
    margin:0 auto; left:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:100
}
```

```html
<div class="itemsContainer">
    <div class="image"> <a href="#">  <img src="http://cbs.umn.edu/sites/cbs.umn.edu/files/public/african_lion_king-wide_1.jpg" style="height:100px" /> </a></div>
    <div class="play"><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flavour/button_play_blue.png" /> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thanks a lot :D